# Does this peripheral exist? Bluetooth To 3.5mm audio

Tags: audio, bluetooth, product-rec

I'm looking for a device that receives audio via bluetooth and outputs it via 3.5mm audio jack. The purpose of this would be to plug it into my car's 3.5mm audio jack and leave it there, and connect to it via iPhone to route music through it to the car. Does this exist, and if so where can I find it? I can't seem to find it.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** To clarify - I can find products like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DTRO9Q) but I want the opposite. This sends audio from the 3.5mm end out via bluetooth. I want it to receive the audio via bluetooth and output to the 3.5mm end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen these, but only as part of integrated headset/transmitter packages.  That said, a Google search for [audio bluetooth receiver](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=audio%20bluetooth%20receiver&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) finds quite a few likely products.

---

EDIT: oddly enough, substituting "receiver" for "transmitter" worked. :)

Comment: From your search I found [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H2430LL/A/Belkin-Wireless-Bluetooth-Music-Receiver) to be the most prominent but it needs to be plugged into power to work. Ideally, something with battery would be nice, or at least come with a car port power plug.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for 'bluetooth stereo receiver' I purchased two on ebay (from China) and they charge via a mini usb a plug and I can plug any headphones or speakers in via the 3.5mm plug. I use one for my headphones and have some old 5.1 PC speakers plugged into the other one. The great thing is that any of my bluetooth A2DP devices can be paired and played through either.

In fact this is the exact one I purchased: http://www.ebay.com/itm/BLUETOOTH-HEADSET-A2DP-STEREO-AUDIO-DONGLE-RECEIVER-3-5MM-FOR-PC-LAPTOP-PHONES-/290693666326?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43aeb15616#ht_4896wt_1402 (only $17)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rig something for the same purpose by [reporposing a bluetooth headset](https://superuser.com/questions/860540/might-using-bluetooth-headsets-to-output-audio-damage-them). Since the optional audio-in jack is **wired directly to the speakers**, it can also function as an audio-out when the headset is receiving music over bluetooth.