# Might using Bluetooth headsets to output audio damage them?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, risk

My current workstation has no audio card, so I've been listening to music via a Bluetooth headset and a USB bluetooth dongle. Since the headset has a jack for optional cable audio in, I figured that it may be possible to *output* the audio through the *input* jack while the headset is receiving data via bluetooth. Sure enough, I can feed music **into the headset via bluetooth** and **output via the 'input' jack**:

[image: out through the in door]

**Might I risk damaging the headset by repurposing its audio input jack as an audio output jack?**

Comment: Of course, I am listening to the [proper music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa8J-GTp96s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o problem, and my compliments for finding out that the jack is both input and output.
No voltage is fed into an input audio jack (unless the jack is *specifically* for old condenser mikes, and not a standard mini-phone jack), so your headset is safe. That seems like an easy way to make an extension speaker. :-)